# Is it just me? MathJax rendering differences

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

Two questions are cross posted to Maths and Stats:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304205/spherical-gaussian-sigma-dimension#question
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50002/spherical-gaussian-sigma-dimension

The MathJax rendering look visibly different to me:

[image: Mathematics Version]

versus

[image: Cross Validated Version]

Notice in particular the really ugly square root sign on Maths.

**Questions**:

1. Am I the only one seeing this?
2. Any ideas how to fix this?

FWIW: I know that this is definitely browser dependent. The screenshots below are taken with IceWeasel 10 on Debian. Using Epithany I see a different defect on the square root symbol, which occurs for *both* the Maths and the CrossValidated versions (in other words, both appear broken the same way).

Comment: here's the nodirected link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304205/spherical-gaussian-sigma-dimension?noredirect=1  and it looks good for me. Firefox 18.0.2 WindowsXP

Comment: Your font is horrid. Change it.

Comment: Could you provide your browser version and OS? These are very likely bugs on the MathJax side (especially Chrome suffers from this type of problem). you could report those at [the MathJax issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax/issues)

Comment: @Peter: He wrote those details in the last paragraph. IceWeasel 10 on Debian. Or do you mean a complete detailed version of the OS (uname -a sort of output)? [Also, fancy seeing you here!]

Comment: Thanks Asaf. I was confused by the "screenshots below".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suffered from the same problem on Debian, iceweasel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MathJax seems to have a problem rendering that particular radical at particular font sizes.

The default font size on CrossValidated seems to be larger than on Mathematics. Using Firefox 16.0.1 on MacOS, when I increase the display size on Mathematics, it looks good, and when I decrease the display size on CrossValidated, it looks bad:

[image]

Comment: I tried enlarging, but the font on MSE looks... brittle. The font on CV looks much better, it looks full.